# Sorting fasta file by chromosome in a specific and pre-defined orders

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a fasta file that looks like the following:

```
  >chr1
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    .....
  >chr2
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    .....
```

I am trying to sort the file by the chromosome number exactly like the following:

```
>chr1
>chr2   
>chr3   
.
.
.
>chr22
>chrX
>chrY
>chrM
```

However, I have the following orders:

```
>chr1
>chr1_KI270706v1_random
>chr1_KI270707v1_random
>chr1_KI270708v1_random
>chr1_KI270709v1_random
>chr1_KI270710v1_random
>chr1_KI270711v1_random
>chr1_KI270712v1_random
>chr1_KI270713v1_random
>chr1_KI270714v1_random
>chr2
>chr2_KI270715v1_random
>chr2_KI270716v1_random
>chr3
>chr3_GL000221v1_random
>chr4
>chr4_GL000008v2_random
>chr5
>chr5_GL000208v1_random
>chr6
>chr7
>chr8
>chr9
>chr9_KI270717v1_random
>chr9_KI270718v1_random
>chr9_KI270719v1_random
>chr9_KI270720v1_random
>chr10
>chr11
>chr11_KI270721v1_random
>chr12
>chr13
>chr14
>chr14_GL000009v2_random
>chr14_GL000194v1_random
>chr14_GL000225v1_random
>chr14_KI270722v1_random
>chr14_KI270723v1_random
>chr14_KI270724v1_random
>chr14_KI270725v1_random
>chr14_KI270726v1_random
>chr15
>chr15_KI270727v1_random
>chr16
>chr16_KI270728v1_random
>chr17
>chr17_GL000205v2_random
>chr17_KI270729v1_random
>chr17_KI270730v1_random
>chr18
>chr19
>chr20
>chr21
>chr22
>chr22_KI270731v1_random
>chr22_KI270732v1_random
>chr22_KI270733v1_random
>chr22_KI270734v1_random
>chr22_KI270735v1_random
>chr22_KI270736v1_random
>chr22_KI270737v1_random
>chr22_KI270738v1_random
>chr22_KI270739v1_random
>chrEBV
>chrM
>chrUn_GL000195v1
>chrUn_GL000213v1
>chrUn_GL000214v1
>chrUn_GL000216v2
>chrUn_GL000218v1
>chrUn_GL000219v1
>chrUn_GL000220v1
>chrUn_GL000224v1
>chrUn_GL000226v1
>chrUn_KI270302v1
>chrUn_KI270303v1
>chrUn_KI270304v1
>chrUn_KI270305v1
>chrUn_KI270310v1
>chrUn_KI270311v1
>chrUn_KI270312v1
>chrUn_KI270315v1
>chrUn_KI270316v1
>chrUn_KI270317v1
>chrUn_KI270320v1
>chrUn_KI270322v1
>chrUn_KI270329v1
>chrUn_KI270330v1
>chrUn_KI270333v1
>chrUn_KI270334v1
>chrUn_KI270335v1
>chrUn_KI270336v1
>chrUn_KI270337v1
>chrUn_KI270338v1
>chrUn_KI270340v1
>chrUn_KI270362v1
>chrUn_KI270363v1
>chrUn_KI270364v1
>chrUn_KI270366v1
>chrUn_KI270371v1
>chrUn_KI270372v1
>chrUn_KI270373v1
>chrUn_KI270374v1
>chrUn_KI270375v1
>chrUn_KI270376v1
>chrUn_KI270378v1
>chrUn_KI270379v1
>chrUn_KI270381v1
>chrUn_KI270382v1
>chrUn_KI270383v1
>chrUn_KI270384v1
>chrUn_KI270385v1
>chrUn_KI270386v1
>chrUn_KI270387v1
>chrUn_KI270388v1
>chrUn_KI270389v1
>chrUn_KI270390v1
>chrUn_KI270391v1
>chrUn_KI270392v1
>chrUn_KI270393v1
>chrUn_KI270394v1
>chrUn_KI270395v1
>chrUn_KI270396v1
>chrUn_KI270411v1
>chrUn_KI270412v1
>chrUn_KI270414v1
>chrUn_KI270417v1
>chrUn_KI270418v1
>chrUn_KI270419v1
>chrUn_KI270420v1
>chrUn_KI270422v1
>chrUn_KI270423v1
>chrUn_KI270424v1
>chrUn_KI270425v1
>chrUn_KI270429v1
>chrUn_KI270435v1
>chrUn_KI270438v1
>chrUn_KI270442v1
>chrUn_KI270448v1
>chrUn_KI270465v1
>chrUn_KI270466v1
>chrUn_KI270467v1
>chrUn_KI270468v1
>chrUn_KI270507v1
>chrUn_KI270508v1
>chrUn_KI270509v1
>chrUn_KI270510v1
>chrUn_KI270511v1
>chrUn_KI270512v1
>chrUn_KI270515v1
>chrUn_KI270516v1
>chrUn_KI270517v1
>chrUn_KI270518v1
>chrUn_KI270519v1
>chrUn_KI270521v1
>chrUn_KI270522v1
>chrUn_KI270528v1
>chrUn_KI270529v1
>chrUn_KI270530v1
>chrUn_KI270538v1
>chrUn_KI270539v1
>chrUn_KI270544v1
>chrUn_KI270548v1
>chrUn_KI270579v1
>chrUn_KI270580v1
>chrUn_KI270581v1
>chrUn_KI270582v1
>chrUn_KI270583v1
>chrUn_KI270584v1
>chrUn_KI270587v1
>chrUn_KI270588v1
>chrUn_KI270589v1
>chrUn_KI270590v1
>chrUn_KI270591v1
>chrUn_KI270593v1
>chrUn_KI270741v1
>chrUn_KI270742v1
>chrUn_KI270743v1
>chrUn_KI270744v1
>chrUn_KI270745v1
>chrUn_KI270746v1
>chrUn_KI270747v1
>chrUn_KI270748v1
>chrUn_KI270749v1
>chrUn_KI270750v1
>chrUn_KI270751v1
>chrUn_KI270752v1
>chrUn_KI270753v1
>chrUn_KI270754v1
>chrUn_KI270755v1
>chrUn_KI270756v1
>chrUn_KI270757v1
>chrX
>chrY
>chrY_KI270740v1_random
```

So my aim is to sort the headers like this:

```
>chr1
>chr2   
>chr3   
.
.
.
>chr22
>chrX
>chrY
>chrM
```

and the remaining headers are sorted after the above order, how can I accomplish this?

I tried different technique but non actually works.

For example:

```
bioawk -c fastx '{print}' in.fa | sort -k1,1V | awk '{print ">"$1;print $2}'
```

but that did not work.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You talk about sorting the headers, but also about sorting the file.  I suspect you mean that you want to sort all the *entries* (header + sequence) by header. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. sorting the entries by the header.

Answer (score 1):

index the fasta with `samtools faidx src.fa`

and then

```
for C in chrA chrB chrC chrD
do
    samtools faidx src.fa "${C}" >> dest.fa
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please clarify what this code is doing and how is it used to sort the chromosomes in the aforementioned order ?

Comment: The code above uses your predefined array of chromosome names (chrA chrB chrC etc.) in a loop to extract each one and dump them into a new dest.fa fasta file. Here, samtools faidx is simply extracting each individual chromosome from the original src.fa file. The dest.fa file will include chromosome header and seq in the order you specified in the loop array.